# Chmodded 000 the home folder,now unable to log in

Tags: login, chmod

I accidentally issued the following command `sudo chmod 000 /home/username/`. And now I'm unable to log in. Also when I'm trying from the bash shell, my home folder is appearing as "Access-your-private-data.desktop". Any ideas about how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to log in via command line.

Upon login screen, hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to switch to console tty and try to log in there with your normal account.

If this is successful you would eventually be able to apply `sudo chmod 755 /home/username/`

Let us know if this works.

Comment: I'm glad to hear! :-)

Comment: If you feel that @cauon answer helped you to fix the issue. Please mark the answer as accepted answer by clicking on the grey tick mark. Thanks.

Comment: @cauon Why `sudo`? In this situation, the user still owns his/her home folder, it's just the *permissions* that have changed. So `chmod` should succeed even when not run as `root`.

Comment: @EliahKagan I wasn't sure about this and had no machine to test :-) It was just precaution.